# Change path in react router without causing re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following route:

`<Route path="/cases" component={Cases} />`

This route handles the following example paths

```
/cases
/cases/1
```

I have an iframe in this route that is responsible for handing all user interactions. On a location change in the iframe, the iframe posts a message to the parent window notifying it that the url has changed.

I want to be able to change the route in the parent window without re-rendering the iframe.

This is my current solution

```
this.props.history.replace(pathnameFromIframe);

shouldComponentUpdate = () => {
    return false;
}
```

This solution works but it goes against the React docs:

> shouldComponentUpdate ... method only exists as a performance
>   optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a rendering, as this can
>   lead to bugs.
>
> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Can I solve this some other way?

Is it perhaps possible to change the route without adding the route as a prop in the component? This would solve the problem I believe.

Answer (score 0):

i think hashHistory what u need? if im not mistaken

```
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router';


hashHistory.push({
    pathname:"/url-url",

  });
```